# System.Array [] not compatible with float [] [] in F#

Tags: f#, polymorphism

I need to call a function that takes `System.Array []` as one parameter in F#. (The function is in a library).
I need to pass an argument of type `float [] [] []` but the compiler refuses to compile. To replicate the problem, I wrote the following code

```
let x : float [] [] = Array.init 2 (fun x -> Array.zeroCreate 3)
x :> System.Array;; // This is OK

val x : float [] [] = [|[|0.0; 0.0; 0.0|]; [|0.0; 0.0; 0.0|]|]

> x :> System.Array [];; //Error

  x :> System.Array [];;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(14,1): warning FS0059: The type 'System.Array []' does not have any proper subtypes and need not be used as the target of a static coercion

  x :> System.Array [];;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(14,1): error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    float [] []    
is not compatible with type
    System.Array []    
The type 'System.Array' does not match the type 'float []'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
let x : float [] [] = Array.init 2 (fun x -> Array.zeroCreate 3)

let toArray (xs : #System.Array []) =
    Array.map (fun x -> x :> System.Array) xs

let x' : System.Array [] = toArray x
```

Comment: That's what exactly I just thought of. And I will use it for now. But I am still wondering whether there is a way to cast it directly.

Comment: Not in F#, yes in C# (one of the -variances).

Answer (score 4):

The ability to treat an `'s[]` as a `'t[]` when `'s :> 't` makes the .NET type system unsound (and is probably due to the fact that Java does the same thing).  Unfortunately, C# follows .NET in allowing this.

Because it's a .NET runtime feature, you can also do it in F# via boxing and unboxing:

```
let x : float[][] = Array.init 2 (fun x -> Array.zeroCreate 3)
let x' = (box x) :?> System.Array[]
```

This avoids the overhead of mapping each element as in Ramon's solution.

To see why this makes the .NET type system unsound, consider this:

```
x'.[0] <- upcast [| "test" |] // System.ArrayTypeMismatchException
```

Even though we are storing a value of type `System.Array` into a `System.Array[]`, we get an exception at runtime because the true type of the underlying array can't support the operation (`x` and `x'` are just two views of the same array, and obviously a `string[]` can't be stored into `x`).  This unsoundness in the .NET type system therefore has the undesirable side effect of requiring additional overhead for most stores into arrays to ensure that the stored value has a type compatible with the underlying array.  In my opinion, it's a good thing that F# prevents you from doing this directly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this problem. I was actually confused by this behavior when I first learned that I could do this in both Java and C#, and it turns out that array type is covariant in both languages. It turns out that F# just chooses to return to the normal sense of inheritance.